# The command 'startx' only works when entered in the terminal and not from a bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, console, x11, xorg

I wrote a rule in /etc/udev.rules.d/ that runs a bash script '/home/pi/startx.sh' if a device is plugged into my Raspberry Pi 4. This rule works, in the sense that if in my script I write

```
#!/bin/bash
touch test.txt
```

the test.txt file is actually created each time I insert e.g. a keyboard. Now I would like this script to run the startx command as the user 'pi'.
In practice, I want the Raspberry to start in console mode and starts the 'pi' user's desktop only if this device is inserted through the script startx.sh.

Now if in my script I write

```
#!/bin/bash
startx
```

it doesn't work and the pi's Xorg Desktop doesn't start.

If I try to run it from ssh it says (well, i dont care to start it via ssh, it was only a try):
parse_vt_settings /dev/tty0 (permission denied)

The really absurd thing is that if I run the startx command from the keyboard in front of the monitor startx works without problems (always as user pi).
What's more, if I run the script ./startx.sh from the console when I'm physically in front of the monitor it works perfectly.

It is important to specify that I want the Desktop to start as the user 'pi' and not as root or other users.
So the command sudo startx is not suitable (which works by giving me obviously another Desktop that is not pi's).

I also don't want to change any permissions on tty, video, etc. because if it works from the console when I'm physically in front of the monitor, I don't understand why it can't work from a bash script.

OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Raspberry pi 4

I tried modifying the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
startx
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u pi startx
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash -l
sudo -u pi startx
```

and also

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -i -u pi xinit
```

without any result.

Comment: I think you can do it with `chvt 8` followed by `startx -- vt8 -keeptty` or something along those lines. Sorry for being vague - I forget the exact commands I used.

Comment: Here is a similar Question that might help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478742/error-when-trying-to-use-xorg-only-console-users-are-allowed-to-run-the-x-serve

Comment: both solutions are not working for me: nothing starts with the bash script

Comment: Try running `type startx` in your normal Terminal and you'll see the full path to `startx`. Try using that full path  in your script.

Comment: same result: nothing happen, sorry

Answer (score 0):

"**startx**" will start the Desktop, as long as the Desktop **is not already running**.

You are facing either

- a conflict with a previous Desktop instance, or
- you have not correctly identified the device that the system believes to be the console where the Desktop "must" be displayed, or
- you haven't correctly defined the device for a dual-head Pi, or
- the configuration for that target device is malformed as an intended X display.

To help in assisting you with identifying **process parents and dependencies**, below is a script (reused/modified) to display the processes in a hierarchy tree.  The original was simply called pt.  I call my own **pt.sh**.

```
#!/bin/sh
##################################################################################
### 
### $Id: pt.sh,v 2.4 2022/08/17 22:27:05 root Exp $
### 
### Script to print a process tree on stdout.
###     - easy to see relationships between processes with this script
### Synt: pt [opts] [startPID]
### Opts:   -h,H,-V : help,HELP,version
###     -w width: screen width
###     -o type : output type: 1, 2, or 3 (def 3)
### Parm: startPID: show tree starting at this PID (def: 1)
### 
### @(#) pt - display Process Table "Tree"
### 
### Original Author:  William J. Duncan (prior to May 7 1996)
### 
### Synopsis:
###   pt [opts] [startPID] |  less      # (or whatever your fav pager is)
### 
### Notes:
###   - all recent implementations of awk I have seen have recursion.
###     It is a requirement.  This is a nice little example of using
###     recursion in awk.
### 
###   - under bsd, there was no real happy mix of options which
###     would pick up a user's name, and do everything else we wanted.
###     (eg. need to pick up PPID for example)
###     So we need to do a separate search through the passwd entries
###     ourselves and build a lookup table, or alternatively run ps
###     twice.
### 
###   - notice the ugliness of 3 separate sets of quotes required in
###     the line:
###       while ("'"$GETPASSWD"'" | getline > 0)
### 
###     The inside pair of quotes keeps the 2 tokens for the command
###     together.  The pair of single quotes escapes from within the
###     awk script to the "outside" which is the shell script.  This
###     makes the shell variable "$GETPASSWD" available for use with-
###     in the awk script as a literal string.  (Which is the reason
###     for the outside pair of double quotes.)
### 
###   - This is the general format of including awk scripts within
###     the shell, and passing ENVIRONMENT variables down.    -wjd
### 
##################################################################################

##################################################################################
###
### Mods by E. Marceau, Ottawa, Canada
### 
###   - Added logic to determine max length of username for proper display of that field
### 
##################################################################################

TMP=/tmp/`basename "$0" ".sh" `.$$

set -u
## Constants
  rcsid='$Id: pt.sh,v 2.4 2022/08/17 22:27:05 root Exp $'
  P=`basename $0`;
  ## This command should list the password file on on "all" systems, even
  ## if YP is not running or 'ypcat' does not exist.
  ## List the local password file first because the UIDS array is assigned
  ## such that later entries override earlier entries.

  if [ -z "`which ypcat 2>>/dev/null `" ]
  then
     GETPASSWD="(cat /etc/passwd)"
  else
     GETPASSWD="(ypcat passwd 2>/dev/null)"
  fi

## Name: usage;   Desc: standard usage description function
   usage() { awk 'NF==0{if(n++=='${1:-0}')exit}0==0'<$0; }

maxWidth=0

## check for options
   set -- `getopt ehHVw:o: ${*:-}`
   test $? -ne 0  &&  usage 0  &&  exit 9
   for i in $*; do
        case $i in
        -e)     maxWidth=1    ;  COLS=512 ; shift   ;;
        -h)     usage 0 && exit 9                       ;;
        -H)     usage 1 && exit 9                       ;;
    -V) echo "${P} ${rcsid}"|cut -d' ' -f1,4-5; exit;;
    -w) COLS=$2       ;  shift 2        ;;
    -o)     outtype=$2    ;  shift 2        ;;
        --)     shift         ;  break          ;;
        esac
   done

## initialize
   startpid="${1:-1}"
   SYSTEM=${SYSTEM:-`uname`}
   outtype="${outtype:-3}"

case ${SYSTEM} in
    #    XENIX)          # or any other sys5 i think
    #        PS=/bin/ps
    #        AWK=/bin/awk
    #        PSFLAGS=-ef
    #        SYSTEM=sys5
    #        SIZE='/bin/stty size'
    #        ;;
    #    SunOS)          # bsd flavours of ps
    #        os=`uname -r | cut -c1`
    #        PS=/bin/ps
    #        AWK=nawk
    #   if test "$os" = "4"; then
    #           PSFLAGS=-axjww
    #           SYSTEM=bsd
    #           SIZE='/bin/stty size'
    #   else
    #           PSFLAGS=-ef
    #           SYSTEM=sys5
    #           SIZE='/usr/ucb/stty size'
    #   fi
    #   ;;
    #    HP-UX)
    #        PS=/bin/ps
    #       AWK=/usr/bin/awk
    #        PSFLAGS=-ef
    #        SYSTEM=sys5
    #        SIZE='/bin/stty size'
    #        ;;
    Linux)
        PS=/bin/ps
        AWK=awk
        PSFLAGS=-axjww
        SYSTEM=bsd
        SIZE='/bin/stty size'
    ;;
    *)
        PS=/bin/ps
        AWK=awk
        PSFLAGS=-axjww
        SYSTEM=bsd
        SIZE='/bin/stty size'
        ;;
esac

COLShere=`${SIZE} | awk '{print $2}' `
COLS=${COLS:-$COLShere}
COLS=${COLS:-80}

echo "\t    [1] ${COLS}"

${PS} ${PSFLAGS} | 
${AWK} -v maxWidth="${maxWidth}" 'BEGIN{  lowestPID=9999 ;
        FS = ":" ;
        while ("'"${GETPASSWD}"'" | getline > 0){
            UIDS[ $3 ] = $1 ;
        } ;
        UIDS[ 0 ] = "root" ;                # fix for "extra" root accounts

        for ( var in UIDS ){
            lenT=length( UIDS[var] ) ;
            if ( lenT > lenM ){
                lenM=lenT ;         # longest=UIDS[var] ;
            } ;
        } ;

        printf("%6s %6s %4s  %-"lenM"s %s\n", "PID", "PPID", "TTY", "USER", "COMMAND" ) ;

        FS = " " ;
        COLS='${COLS}' ;
        SYSTEM="'${SYSTEM}'" ;

        if (SYSTEM == "sys5"){
            fpid   = 2 ;
            fppid  = 3 ;
            fuid   = 1 ;
        }else{
            if (SYSTEM == "bsd"){
                fpid   = 2 ;
                fppid  = 1 ;
                fuid   = 8 ;
            } ;
        } ;

        outtype ="'${outtype}'" ;

        if (outtype == 1){
            SPACES=".............................................................................................." ;
            SPREAD=1 ;
            CMD_PREFIX=" " ;
        }else{
            if (outtype == 2){
                SPACES="||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||" ;
                SPREAD=1 ;
                CMD_PREFIX="" ;
            }else{
                SPACES="| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |" ;
                SPREAD=2 ;
                CMD_PREFIX="" ;
            } ;
        } ;
    
    } ;


    NR==1 { title = $0 ; next } ;

    # All others
    {
        if ( $fpid < lowestPID ){ lowestPID=$fpid ; } ;
        LINE[ $fpid  ] = $0  ;                      # Line indexed by PID
        PCNT[ $fppid ]++  ;                         # Index into PPID
        PPID[ $fppid, PCNT[$fppid] ] = $2 ;         # Parent to Children unique

        INDENT=0 ;
    } ;

    function doprint(s, a, name, i, nf, tty, cmd){
        # the splitting and complications here are mostly for
        # sys5, which a different number of fields depending on STIME
        # field.  Argh.
        nf = split(s,a) ;
        for (i=7; i <= nf; i++){
                if (a[i] ~ /[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/){
                break   # set i here
            } ;
        } ;

        for (i++ ; i <= nf; i++){
            name = name " " a[i] ;
        } ;

        if (a[fuid] in UIDS){
            a[fuid] = UIDS[a[fuid]] ;             # if username found
        } ;

        if (SYSTEM == "bsd"){                    # if bsd
            tty = a[5] ;
        }else{                                    # sys5 2 possible formats
            tty = (a[5] ~ /^[0-9]+:/) ? a[6] : a[7] ;
        } ;

        cmd = substr(SPACES,1,INDENT*SPREAD) CMD_PREFIX substr(name,2) ;

        #if ( length(cmd) > COLS-27 && maxWidth == 0 ){
        if ( length(cmd) > COLS-27 ){
            cmd = substr(cmd,1,COLS-27) ;
        } ;

        printf("%6d %6d %4s  %-"lenM"s %s\n", a[fpid], a[fppid], substr(tty,length(tty)-1), a[fuid], cmd ) ;
    } ;

    function dotree(pid) {      # recursive
        if (pid == 0) return

        doprint(LINE[ pid ])
        INDENT++
        while (PCNT[pid] > 0) {
            dotree(PPID[ pid, PCNT[pid] ] ) ;   # recurse
            delete PPID[ pid, PCNT[pid] ] ;
            PCNT[pid]-- ;
        } ;
        INDENT-- ;
    } ;

    END{
        if ( lowestPID > startpid ){ startpid=lowestPID ; } ;
        dotree('${startpid}') ;
    }' >${TMP}.initial


###########################################################################################################################
###
### Additional coding to present results with PID correctly sorted along with associated children also in sorted order.
###
###########################################################################################################################

head -1 ${TMP}.initial >${TMP}.head
tail --lines=+2 ${TMP}.initial | sort --key=1,1n --key=2,2n >${TMP}.remainder

cat ${TMP}.head

while [ true ]
do
        line=`awk '{ if ( NR == 1 ){ print $0 } ; exit }' <${TMP}.remainder `
        first=`echo "${line}" | awk '{ print $1 }' `
        echo "${line}"

        #get children
        tail --lines=+2 ${TMP}.remainder | awk -v pid="${first}" '{ if ( $2 == pid ){ print $0 } ; }' >${TMP}.next
        tail --lines=+2 ${TMP}.remainder | awk -v pid="${first}" '{ if ( $2 != pid ){ print $0 } ; }' >${TMP}.others

        cat ${TMP}.next ${TMP}.others >${TMP}.remainder

        if [ ! -s ${TMP}.remainder ] ; then  break ; fi
done        ###  >${TMP}.new ;cat ${TMP}.new


exit 0
exit 0
exit 0
```

Comment: a conflict with a previous Desktop instance, or
totally correct, but i ask: why when i write startx from the commandline of my machine X works but it dont works either in bash or in ssh? It'`s a clean installation of retropie so i assume quite easy to replicate.

Comment: The dispaly is DISPLAY=:0 Im sure and i dont know what is a dual-head Pi

This guy have the same problem look:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=289786
but its solution doesnt work for me (sudo systemctl start display-manager.service cause i dont have display-manager )

Comment: The environment from the command line MUST be different from the environment when started from bash.  Some of the environment is NOT being exported for availability from bash.  You should save the report for all environment variables for each into a separate file and look for differences that could be the root cause of your issues.

Comment: Are you attempting to run your bash script from a non-X terminal console?

Comment: Eric the bash script is executed automaticalluy by the udev rule.
I think you're right and it's a question of enviroment but if this is the real problem my question is: really is there no way to restart X from a bash script executed by system?
Is there a setting to import all command line environment  in a bash script?
Thanks

Comment: A little recap. 
X is not running.
If I run startx as user pi on the console directly on the raspberry, the command works like a charm and X runs correctly.
If I run as user pi the bash script containing startx from console directly on the raspberry the script works like a charm and X runs correctly.
If I run startx as user pi from ssh (passing the right display) X does not run.
If I run as user pi the bash script containing startx from ssh (passing the right display) X does not run.
If i run startx from a bash command as user pi (sudo -i -u pi startx) from a udev rule, X does not run.

Comment: You have to restart X **from the parent process (A)** of the X session *to ensure that all else (background and support processes) persist unchanged*, without losing info about state/definitions.  To that end, **the ssh must be a parent of process A**, to ensure all that environment remains live and persists, to allow a successful restart of X, without the connection breaking down.  Does that make sense to you ?

Comment: What you're saying is very close to my understanding limits of Linux environments but I think I understand some of it. What doesn't make sense to me is that you are saying that in order to properly restart X I need to take parameters that the user pi uses to keep it alive. Okay. But in my case, X is not started at all and therefore it should not be restarted but started from scratch. Have I missed something?

Comment: There are OS defaults that lay the groundwork for starting X. Those defaults would be in either the .bashrc (if that is your shell) or in config files used by startx. ... ... Going on a tangent here, does the Pi allow you to perform something line this:  **sudo systemctl restart display-manager** or **sudo service lightdm restart** (for Xubuntu Linux) ?

Comment: Would [**this**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/create-new-user-and-enable-autologon-startx-lxde) be helpful?

Comment: It gives for both the same error:
Failed to restart display-manager.service: Unit display-manager.service not found.
Failed to restart lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not found.
i triyed from ssh

Comment: I have to leave this to more knowledgeable people.